# Useful JS libraries for a completely custom form?

Tags: javascript, custom-form, jsom, list-form, sharepoint-rest-api

I've got a page with some special UI requirements that I will need to create via custom client-side code.

I am going to need to nest data from a child-table (plus ability to insert new) into a specific area of an edit form for the parent-table. 
For this requirement, I am going to need to load, render and edit the related sub-table list items client-side.

I know there are dozens of JS libraries that render tables and/or bind data.  (JQuery, bootstrap and Jquery-UI are already used on the site.)  They all vary in their quality and usefulness based on what they are being used for, and probably several aren't useful in the context of binding to Sharepoint data.

Are there libraries that people have used to custom render Sharepoint list data that really brought value to the process?  Possibly a good binding library to keep loading and saving edits simple?  Maybe a datatable control that works well with CSOM or the SP RestApi?

Comment: I'm finding that datatables.net is quite nice for table display of data

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for an easy/clear way to get started with forms in SharePoint without using infopath. I'd look at Stratus Forms(JS Library), you can always get more advanced once you've got the basic functionality roughed out. You may find that the functionality built in is good enough for your needs.